# regex code to filter this type of combo email

Tags: windows, regex

Input txt file:

```
179819085:best-boy23@seznam.cz:0179819085:548af13bdd5fc92c120491aef92f9a22:John:John:Pepa:1975-08-08:37:M:65:969:900563
```

Output txt file:

```
best-boy23@seznam.cz:548af13bdd5fc92c120491aef92f9a22
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created ***THREE*** accounts.  If you can still access the first account (under which you asked the above question), you should go back to using it, and, ideally, register it.  Otherwise, you should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your original account merged with the one you can still access. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, you asked the question using http://superuser.com/users/663212/manik and you posted your most recent “answer” using http://superuser.com/users/663423/manik.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.  … … … … … … … … … … … …  P.S. You also have http://superuser.com/users/663283/manik, but I see no reason why you should keep using that.

Comment: Also, you should clarify your question. What version of Windows are you using? Do you require a solution that works in pure, out-of-the box Windows, or do you have some third-party tools available, or are you willing to install same? Have you ever heard of Cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
echo 179819085:best-boy23@seznam.cz:0179819085:548af13bdd5fc92c120491aef92f9a22:John:John:Pepa:1975-08-08:37:M:65:969:900563 \
    | awk -F: '{print $2":"$4}'
best-boy23@seznam.cz:548af13bdd5fc92c120491aef92f9a22
```

or, having an input file:

```
cat input.txt | awk -F: '{print $2":"$4}'
```

Comment: sorry, since windows tag got added, I can still point out that `awk` is still an option (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows), although I'm not sure how relevant it is. You'll probably have some "native" solution.